# Amazon ECS schedule container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

How can I schedule a container to turn off overnight according to a specified time zone in Amazon ECS?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running an ECS service, you can use time-based auto-scaling to scale down to 0 task instances of that service at a specific time of day, and scale-up to 1 or more instances of that task at another time.

All schedules like this in AWS use the UTC time zone. You would have to convert the times in your time zone to UTC before configuring the schedule.

Comment: Is that configuration set in the service? I don't see where the menu for those parameters is.

Comment: Here's the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/userguide/application-auto-scaling-scheduled-scaling.html